# Error Connecting GCP CloudSql using Sequilize through nodejs in app engine?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

When I try to connect second generation Cloud mysql with app engine using sequilize it give me following Error:

**{"name":"SequelizeConnectionError","parent":{"errno":"ENOENT","code":"ENOENT","syscall":"connect","address":"/cloudsql/phrasal-charger-215107:asia-south1:newdish123","fatal":true},"original":{"errno":"ENOENT","code":"ENOENT","syscall":"connect","address":"/cloudsql/phrasal-charger-215107:asia-south1:newdish123","fatal":true}}**

> Sequelize option set:-

```
const db = new Sequelize(
  config.database.db,
  config.database.username,
  config.database.password,
  {
    host:'localhost',
    dialect: "mysql",
    port: 3306,
    dialectOptions: {
        socketPath: '/cloudsql/phrasal-charger-215107:asia-south1:newdish123'
    }
  }
);
```

> app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex


beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: phrasal-charger-215107:asia-south1:newdish123
```

---

*MORE INFO*

I tried putting '/cloudsql/phrasal-charger-215107:asia-south1:newdish123' in host didn't work.

when I put public ip address in the host given by CloudSQL and setting my ip with GCP as authorised ip then the sequelize is running perfectly and performing operation as expected.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem using the mysql node library, so I think it's got more to do with the proxy. I believe ENOENT means the /cloudsql/ directory is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the exact same issue, all of my code base didn't change at all. What I did to fix it was to create a new project and then create new App Engine Instance and a new Cloud SQL database in my new project.

Then I enabled SQL Admin for the project, created a new profile by running

```
gcloud init
```

and creating a new profile for the new project.

Then I deployed the app again:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

You can find the setup of my project here:

[Node.JS on Google App Enging with Cloud SQLError: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388330/node-js-on-google-app-enging-with-cloud-sqlerror-connect-enoent-cloudsql?noredirect=1#comment93710509_53388330)

Answer (score 1):

Manually add the IP addresses of machines/networks that need access to Cloud SQL to the Authorized Networks section.

And

Check your proxy while making connection

Comment: This will work for dev connections from your local machine, but the app engine VM IP can change from time to time, so this will only work temporarily.